# Not using iterators into a resized vectors

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

I read in The C++ Programming Language : Special Edition

`Don't use iterators into a resized vector`

Consider this example.

```
vector< int >::iterator it = foo.begin();

while ( it != foo.end() ) {
  if ( // something ) {
    foo.push_back( // some num );
  }
  ++it;
}
```

Is there a problem with this? After the vector was resized, would the foo.end() in the loop condition be pushed forward 1?

P.S. In addition, what if vector had reserved space for x number of ints. If push_back didn't violate this space, would it still be an issue ( I would assume so if it.end() points to one past the last element in the vector that contains something ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem with it.

Any call to `push_back` has the potential to invalidate *all* iterators into a vector.

`foo.end()` will always retrieve the valid end iterator (which may be different to the value last returned by `foo.end()`), but `it` may have been invalidated. This means that incrementing it or comparing it may caused undefined behaviour.

Comment: What if the vector had been sized to fit say 10 ints. Assuming that push_back doesn't go over this preallocated size, will it still invalidate the iterators?

Comment: @Person: Strictly, if `push_back` doesn't cause a vector's `size()` to exceed a requested capacity previously given in a call to `reserve` then you are guaranteed that that call to `push_back` won't cause reallocation and won't invalidate iterators to objects. You would still have to call `end()` to get the correct `end()`, though.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's better just to not dance with reserving space and using iterators, and rather just use array indices in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a problem. Regardless of `foo.end()`, `it` may be invalidated by the `push_back()`. Edit: (i.e. it's not *just* that the end could change; it's possible that the *whole* buffer for the vector may be reallocated, so **all** iterators become invalid).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a problem with that. `push_back` invalidates any iterators for the vector you called it on. So after calling `push_back`, it is not even legal to execute `++it`. This is a case of undefined behavior, so it may sometimes work and it may sometimes fail but you should never rely on it working.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the push_back() may invalidate all iterators to the vector. The reason for this is that the data in a vector is stored in a region of contiguous memory. If the push_back() or any other operation that resizes the vector causes the size of the vector to go over the capacity of the allocated region that region will be reallocated and end up at a different place in memory, while all the iterators will still be referencing the old memory region.